# How to set ActionBar background in ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;` to use ActionBar before API 11.
I set ActionBar background as below code after API 11:

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.top_bar_bg));
```

Byt I don't know how to do that before API 11.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the support library you should include `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`. So try-

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.top_bar_b‌​g));
```